# Building libharu from scratch

Tags: visual-c++, zlib, libpng, libharu

Recently I'm trying to build and use libharu library in order to create PDFs from bitmaps.

I've made some research trough it's site : http://libharu.org/. 
There are instructions showing how to build it, but i doesn't build because it has dependencies to two other libraries(which i don't understand how to integrate in the building process) - zlib and libpng.

But i cant understand clearly the entire process so my last hope is if someone has built it from scratch and could explain me or provide me with some details for the building process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibHaru was forked after 2.0.8. The later version uses a make system whose code seems to have changed. First of the new variant was 2.10.0. Old version is on sourceforge.

I couldn't get later version to compile but 2.0.8 worked. (dated 2006) In the past I have seen comment suggesting I am not alone. You are correct there are no instructions about the dependencies. If you can you should use the pre-built version, which is mentioned.

From your message I assume you have little software building experience. Outlining in a few words if not feasible, here is a little. Dependent libraries have to be available, either as source for compiling, or occasionally as pre-built libraries specifically for the compiler/OS you are using. You have to go and get them. Then the compiler system you are using to build libharu, has to be able to "see" the dependent libraries, in this case the *.h file. After compiling the whole lot has to be linked together. None of this is rocket science but is a major source of frustration, everything has to be just right, usually with nothing to tell you what is wrong.

And that is why some people favor using a third party "build" tool. If it works.

libharu has two major dependencies: zlib and libpng, both widely used libraries which usually compile easily but I think there are ways to omit these for a loss of functionality, are about handling import of bitmaps.

So you have three sets of sources and essentially three libraries where as a final step are linked to from the libharu source code.

Alternatively you could find a pre-built version.